# One item per line in Infinitegrid

Tags: javascript, vue.js, infinitegrid

I use Grid layout to position the item boxes as infinite stream already. I have a second use case for infinite dynamic loading of data but its intended presentation will vary. Here is plain old list of links. GridLayout does not fit there and no other layout does. How can I position one item per line?

```
<GridLayout
ref="ig"
:options="options"
:layoutOptions="layoutOptions"
@append="onAppend"
@layout-complete="onLayoutComplete"
>
  <div v-for="item in list" :key="item._id" :groupKey="item.groupKey">
    {{ item.caption }}
  </div>
</GridLayout>
```

[image]

I have tried to wrap it in DIV but Infinitegrid keeps append the absolute position style.

Code sand box: https://3j97x.csb.app/

Answer (score 1):

How about making the width of the item 100%?

Comment: I decided not to use infinitegrid for this particular use case.